# How to achieve element height transition when target height is not known (not fixed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to achieve element height transition when target height is not known?

If I replace `height: unset` with `height: 100px` the animation works. The problem is that height should be computed based on the content, and is not the same for all elements.

Similarily, if I use `max-height` instead of `height`, I have to put an hardcoded value (e.g. `1000px`) but it has the drawback that for a short item, most of the transition time, no animation is being played.

```js
$('.c').change(function() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var item = $('#item' + i)
        if($('#c' + i).prop('checked')) item.addClass('show')
        else item.removeClass('show')
    }
})
```

```css
.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.item.show {
    height: unset;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="c" id="c1" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" class="c" id="c2" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="c" id="c3" checked />
</div>
<div class="items">
    <div id="item1" class="item show">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="item3" class="item show">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for pure css solution ?

Comment: If the css solution is doable and simple that would be preferable. If it is overly complex with respect to a jQuery one liner, the latter is preferred :)

Comment: Simple CSS solution I wouldn't count on it, it'll either look funny *using the transform approach* or require a fixed width *using flex, height or max-height*, JS solution a quick google search would get you ton of JS solutions, which makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: I tried transform, but that won't change the div height

Comment: Yes, Transforms are merely visual that's why they only affect overflow

Answer (score 1):

You might set element's `height` to its `scrollHeight`.

jQuery solution:

```js
$('.c').change(function() {
  const c = $(this);
  const item = $(c.attr('rel'));
  item.css({
    height: item[0].scrollHeight * c.prop('checked')
  })
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="c" rel="#item1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="c" rel="#item2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="c" rel="#item3" />
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div id="item1" class="item">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="item2" class="item">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="item3" class="item">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```